# UITableview not removing from superview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am going to delete  cells in my `UITableView` using a button in the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ATTACHMENTCELL", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentTableViewCell
    if let obj=dm.arrayImageTable[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
    {
        cell.lblTitle.text=obj["DocumentName"] as? String
        //cell.tag=obj["EmployeeCode"] as! Int
        cell.lblTitle.textColor=com.getfontColor()
        cell.imgvw.image=obj["Imag"] as? UIImage
        cell.btnDel.tag=indexPath.row
        cell.btnDel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeFromTable(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    return cell
}


func removeFromTable(sender:UIButton)
{

    var index:Int=sender.tag
    if(index>=dm.arrayImageTable.count)
    {
        index=0
        dm.arrayImageTable.remove(at: 0)
        dm.arrayAttachedDoc.remove(at: 0)
    }
    else
    {
        dm.arrayImageTable.remove(at: index)
        dm.arrayAttachedDoc.remove(at: index)
    }

    self.tblImage.deleteRows(at: [NSIndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .left)

    var btnFrame=self.btnApplyLeave.frame
    btnFrame.origin.y=self.btnApplyLeave.frame.origin.y-30
   self.btnApplyLeave.frame=btnFrame
    if(dm.arrayImageTable.count<=0)
    {

        self.tblImage.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

But my `UITableView` is not removing although the count is 0. Any one can see where is the wrong I have done?
Please help me

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint at self.tblImage.removeFromSuperview() and check with view debugging if the view is really removed. Maybe setting hidden = true will do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm guessing, at `numberOfRows` you've returned arrayImageTable.count.

So:

```
if(index>=dm.arrayImageTable.count)
    {
        index=0
        dm.arrayImageTable.remove(at: 0)
        dm.arrayAttachedDoc.remove(at: 0)
    }
```

always is wrong. Because indexPath.row can't equal arrayImageTable.count if you return arrayImageTable.count at `numberOfRow`.
Try this:

```
var index = sender.tag == dm.arrayImageTable.count - 1 ? 0 : sender.tag
dm.arrayImageTable.remove(at: 0)
dm.arrayAttachedDoc.remove(at: 0)
self.tblImage.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)], with: .left)
```

Hope It will help you.